# Array of objects with vector as class member

Tags: c++

I have an array of objects that have a vector as a class member (actually it is a struct). The struct is:

```
struct Cell {
  vector<int> borderNodes;
  vector<int> helperNodes;

  int minNodePointer;
  int maxNodePointer;


  Cell() {
    minNodePointer = -1;
    maxNodePointer = -1;
  }

  Cell(int _minNodePointer, int _maxNodePointer) {
    minNodePointer = _minNodePointer;
    maxNodePointer = _maxNodePointer;
  }

  vector<int>& getHelperNodes() {
    return helperNodes;
  }

  vector<int>& getBorderNodes()  {
    return borderNodes;
  }

  void setHelperNodesArray() {
    sort(helperNodes.begin(), helperNodes.end());
  }

  void setBorderNodesArray() {
    sort(borderNodes.begin(), borderNodes.end());
  }
};
```

I have built an array of those objects as a global variable with :

```
Cell* cells = new Cell[maxNumberOfCells];
```

and I want to add some integers to the vectors inside the objects.

I tried this (inside a function):

```
cells[cellId].borderNodes.push_back(node_id);
```

or

```
cells[cellId].getBorderNodes().push_back(node_id);
```

and they compile fine, but nothing is added to the vector. How is the correct way to do this? Here is the function that reads from a db, and adds the integers. The query and reading from db is correct, so no mistakes there.

```
void loadBorderNodesPerCellBnOnly(bool shouldRearrangeNodes, int subtractor, int maxNumberOfCells, int** cellBorderNodes) {
    cellBorderNodes = new int*[maxNumberOfCells];
    try {
        work W(Conn);
        for (int rownum = 0; rownum < r.size(); ++rownum) {
            const result::tuple row = r[rownum];

            vector<string> s = split(row[1].as<string > (), ' ');
            const int mySize = s.size();
            int cellId = row[0].as<int> ();
            cellBorderNodes[cellId] = new int[mySize];
            for (int k = 0; k < mySize; k++) {
                int node_id = atoi(s[k].c_str());
                cellBorderNodes[cellId][k] = node_id;
                (cells[cellId].getBorderNodes()).push_back(node_id);
                try {
                    nodes[node_id - subtractor].cellId = cellId;
                } catch (const std::exception &e) {
                    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
                }
                nodes[node_id - subtractor].isBorderNode = true;
            }
            s.clear();
        }
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }


    for (int k = 0; k < maxNumberOfCells; k++) {
        cout << k << ": " << cells[k].borderNodes.size() << endl;
        cells[k].setBorderNodesArray();
        if (maxBorderNodesPerCell < cells[k].borderNodes.size()) {
            maxBorderNodesPerCell = cells[k].borderNodes.size();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you determining that nothing has been added?

Comment: How do you know nothing is added?

Comment: for (int k = 0; k < maxNumberOfCells; k++) {
        cout << k << ": " << cells[k].borderNodes.size() << endl;
    }

Comment: @AlexandrosE. Can you add to your question the function in which you attempt to do the `push_back` and then output the sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void loadBorderNodesPerCellBnOnly([...], int** cellBorderNodes) {
    cellBorderNodes = new int*[maxNumberOfCells];
```

The function above takes an `int**` by value. The copy is called `cellBorderNodes` inside the function. In the next line you change the value of the **copy** and continue updating that. None of those changes will be visible outside of the function. (And you will leak the acquired memory)

If you want to pass an `int**` and modify it inside the function, consider passing it by reference as in `int**&`. But you might be better off using higher level constructs (pass a `vector<vector<int>>&`, create a type that represents the data and pass it by value...)

Comment: You are correct but my problem is not with cellBorderNodes, is with the cells array. I will fix it but my problem still remains

Comment: The problem was the delimiter used for splitting the string in the db. So now my code works. Thanks everyone for your help